# WMI Batch Script returning No Instance(s) Available

Tags: batch-file, wmi

I am trying to retrieve the timestamp of file in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS  format using WMI in a batch script as below:

```
@echo off
::if "%~1" == "" goto :EOF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::for %%V in (%1) do (

    rem Get name of file with full path.
    set FileName='C:\scot\logs\marker.txt'

    rem Escape each backslash in file path with one more backslash.
    rem set 'FileName=!FileName:\=\\!'

    echo FilePath=%FileName%
    rem Get creation date and time of file in format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.
    ::for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1 delims=." %%T in (`%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where "name='!FileName!'" get CreationDate') do set FileDateTime=%%T

    for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=." %%T in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where "name='!FileName!'" get CreationDate') do set FileDateTime=%%T

    echo FileCreationTime1=%FileDateTime%

    rem The first 8 characters are file creation date.
    set "FileDate=!FileDateTime:~0,8!"
    rem The next 6 characters are file creation time.
    set "FileTime=!FileDateTime:~8,6!"
    echo FileCreationTime2=%FileTime%

    if exist "!FileDate!_!FileTime!-%%~nV%%~xV" (
        echo Cannot rename file: %%~fV
    ) else (
        ren "%%~fV" "!FileDate!-!FileTime!-%%~nV%%~xV"
    echo FileCreationTime=%FileTime%
    )
::)
endlocal
```

but it is returning saying "No Instance(s) Available".

When I run the same WMIC command from command line I am able to get the time stamp value. Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `usebackq` but in the code backquotes are not used.And the doubling of backslashes is commented. Check this example:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe"
set "FileName=!FileName:\=\\!"
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=." %%T in (`"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where name='!FileName!' get CreationDate"`) do set "FileDateTime=%%T"
echo %FileDateTime%
```

As I have no your file  wmic.exe is used to get the time.

EDIT:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "FileName=%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe"
set "FileName=!FileName:\=\\!"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%T in (`"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe DATAFILE where name='!FileName!' get CreationDate /format:value"`) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ("%%T") do  set "FileDateTime=%%#"
)
echo %FileDateTime%
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is working. But I have a problem as below: 
with the above code i am able to get the time partially.
output : 227975+330
Needed : 201605171804417.227975+330
full string of the time